# Solving equations (implicit functions)

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have two equations:

```
eq = {x + y - z == -1, x^2 + y^2 - z == 3};
```

And I would like to get $z(x,y)$ in ordert to do:
$$x+y+1=x^2+y^3-3$$
Then I'd like to do the same thing with $y(x)$ and to plot a graph. I don't understand how to solve the equations though, I get a recursion error:

```
Solve[x + y - z == -1, z]
```

Comment: I still vote to close this question, as it is coming from a simple mistake that can be solved by restarting the kernel. I'm not exactly sure if Joses answer would vanish then. If this is the case, then we should leave it open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@Eliminate[{x + y - z == -1 && x^2 + y^2 - z == 3}, z], 
{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

`Eliminate` helps you to remove a variable from the equations:

```
Eliminate[{x + y - z + 1 == 0 && x^2 + y^2 - z - 3 == 0}, z]

(* 4 + y - y^2 == -x + x^2 *)
```

Comment: thank you, and how can I get the expression y(x)?

Comment: @Gitana, try `Solve[{x + y - z == -1 && x^2 + y^2 - z == 3}, y, z]`.

Answer (score 2):

### Edit:

I just saw that my reading was too sloppy. You want to eliminate z, not x like I did. I'll leave it like that but be aware of it.

Please restart your kernel (Menu -> Evaluation -> Quit Kernel) and try again. You probably have given the variables values because your `Solve` line should evaluate.

Additionally, you can do it all at once

```
Solve[eq, {z, y}]
(* {{z -> 1/2 (3 + 2 x - Sqrt[17 + 4 x - 4 x^2]), 
  y -> 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[17 + 4 x - 4 x^2])}, {z -> 
   3/2 + x + 1/2 Sqrt[17 + 4 x - 4 x^2], 
  y -> 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[17 + 4 x - 4 x^2])}} *)
```

Finally, you don't need explicit functions if you want to plot implicit equations. You can use `ContourPlot` instead. When I understood you correctly, you want to combine both equations and eliminate `x`. After that, you want a plot y against z. This can be done by eliminating `x`:

```
eq2 = Eliminate[eq, x]
(* (-3 - 2 y) z + z^2 == 2 - 2 y - 2 y^2 *)
```

and then plotting it

```
ContourPlot[(-3 - 2 y) z + z^2 == 2 - 2 y - 2 y^2, 
  {y, -3, 3}, {z, -2, 5}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you for the answer, there was a kernel problem as you pointed out!